# 2nd order non-homogenous ODE with delta function & B.C.S

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I'm relatively new to the concept of the Dirac Delta function have come across a problem in dealing with ODE with delta

Solve the ODE:

$$A''(y) - λ^2 A(y) = δ(y - ξ)$$

Subject to B.C (Hint: Use Hyperbolic functions)
$$A(0) = A(b) = 0,$$

For the solution I have assumed $δ(ξ)$ is undefined, So
$$A(y) =
\begin{cases}
Asinh(λy)+BCosh(λy),  & y<ξ &(1) \\
Csinh(λy)+DCosh(λy), & y>ξ&(2)
\end{cases}$$

Using $A(0)=0, \ A(y)=Asinh(λy)$

Using $A(b)=0, \ A(y)=Csinh(λ(b - y))$

Such that;
$$A(y) =
\begin{cases}
Asinh(λy),  & y<ξ &(1) \\
Csinh(λ(b - y), & y>ξ&(2)
\end{cases}$$

What can I do to further simplify my solution, Can I get the constants A , C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $0 < \xi < b$. Let $\epsilon>0$, then take your differential equation and integrate it like so:

$$\int_{\xi-\epsilon}^{\xi+\epsilon} A''(y) - \lambda^2 A(y) dy = \int_{\xi-\epsilon}^{\xi+\epsilon} \delta(y-\xi)dy$$

$$\implies A'\left(\xi+\epsilon\right) - A'\left(\xi-\epsilon\right) -\lambda^2\int_{\xi-\epsilon}^{\xi+\epsilon} A(y)dy = 1$$

Now take the limit as $\epsilon\to 0^+$. By assumption, we want $A(y)$ to be continuous, so the integral term goes to $0$. What we are left with is the following:

$$A'\left(\xi^+\right)-A'\left(\xi^-\right) = 1$$

This is your new condition to solve for the remaining coefficients. The first derivative is not continuous at $y=\xi$, but it has a jump discontinuity that is exactly $1$ in size.

Comment: So do I have to solve a system of equations?

$$A(y) =
\begin{cases}
Asinh(λy),  & y<ξ &(1) \\
Csinh(λ(b - y), & y>ξ&(2)
\end{cases}$$

Since A(y) is continous $\implies$ $Asinh(λy)=Csinh(λ(b - y))$

$$A'(y) =
\begin{cases}
λAcosh(λy),  & y<ξ &(1) \\
-λCcosh(λ(b - y)) +1, & y>ξ&(2)
\end{cases}$$
I've added +1 into A'(y) to make it discontinuous (unsure about this) and this $\implies λAcosh(λy)=-λCcosh(λ(b - y)) +1$

and thus I am left with a system of equations $$λAsinh(λy)=Csinh(λ(b - y))\\
λAcosh(λy)=-λCcosh(λ(b - y)) +1$$

Comment: @DanielChan that is almost exactly correct, except you should've plugged in $\xi$ for $y$. And the $+1$ is on the wrong side